# All icons of pCloud are blurred in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, icons, pcloud

I am using pCloud on Ubuntu 18.04.1 for couple of days. I am trying to replace Dropbox as they will ditch the encrypted file system on Ubuntu.

The problem I noticed with pCloud is that, the icons are blury. Each and every single pCloud icons are blurry. Even the drop down menu bar icons of the top bar (at the left of the Dropbox icon) bar are blurry too. From the following screenshot you can see how blurry the pCloud icons are campared to the other icons. As an example, compare the firefox icon with the pCloud icon or compare the dropbox icon with the pCloud icon on the top right corner. Even the icons shown in the pCloud preferences/settings window are blurred. I've marked the icons with red arrows in the following image.

[image: Blurry pCloud icons indicated with red arrows.]

I've found that at `/home/user_name/.local/share/icons/hicolor` there are several icons of pCloud with different sizes (such as 128x128, 16x16, 24x24, 256x256, 32x32, 48x48, 512x512, 64x64, 96x96). May be these icons are not used properly. By the way, My screen resolution is 2560x1440 (16:9).

How can I mitigate this blurry icon problem?

For the convenience, a screenshot without the arrows is shown below.

[image: blury pCloud icons]

Comment: Please add tag info for the new tag you created: https://askubuntu.com/edit-tag-wiki/8710